# Batch file to write filenames from a directory into a text file with specific format

Tags: batch-file

Wanted to write a batch file that reads file names from a directory and puts them into a text file in the same directory. Twist is that the filenames should have specific format explained below:
Original file names are: ThisThat.shp, HellNono.shp, LifeGood.shp.... and so on.
So the batch file should grab ThisThat, HellNono, LifeGood and put it into a text file like this:

```
ThisThat|ThisThat
HellNono|HellNono
LifeGood|LifeGood
```

filenames should be separated with a separator and each filename in a different line.

This is what I have come up with.

```
cd %1
if exist 8characters.txt del 8characters.txt
for /F "delims=" %%j in ('dir /A-D /B /O') do echo %%~nj >> 8characters.txt
```

This script just grabs filenames and I don't know how to store it in the format explained above.Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly there as `%%~nj` will output the filename as you want it. You just need to output it twice to get the format you want:

```
for /F "delims=" %%j in ('dir /A-D /B /O') do echo %%~nj^|%%~nj>> 8characters.txt
```

Note the `^` character in front of the `|`. The `|` is used to pipe the output to another command so it needs to be escaped and that is done using `^|`